# Dom based Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) sources

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

Which are still relevant sources for Dom-based Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) in 2020?

Had a list of those:

```
document.URL, document.documentURI, document.location, location, location.href, location.search, location.hash, document.referer, window.name
```

But just found out that:

```
window.location.href
```

is now properly encoded on modern browsers so:

Code:

```
<script>
document.write(window.location.href)
</script>
```

PoC

```
http://localhost/#<script>alert(1)</script>
```

Will not work.

Comment: I would say that all are still relevant as there are still users which are using outdated browsers. I wouldn't downgrade any of the possible options when testing application.